Effect of gauge-fixing via Lagrange multipliers on Euler-Lagrange equations
Preamble
Consider the Lagrangian density for electrodynamics:
$$L=-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}-A_\mu J^\mu\tag{1}$$
With the usual definition of $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$. This results in the Euler-Lagrange equations:
$$\partial_\rho F^{\rho\mu}=J^\mu\tag{2}$$
From which we can determine that $$\partial_\mu J^\mu=0,\tag{3}$$ so the vector field can only be consistently coupled to a conserved current. Now let's say we want to fix the gauge via a Lagrange multiplier, using Coulomb gauge. Thus:
$$L=-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}-A_\mu J^\mu+\lambda\partial_i A_i.\tag{4}$$
The Euler-Lagrange equations now are:
$$\partial_i F^{i0}=J^0,\tag{5}$$
$$-\partial_0 F^{k0}+\partial_i F^{ik}-\partial_k \lambda=J^k,\tag{6}$$
$$\partial_i A_i=0.\tag{7}$$
We have Coulomb gauge, but it looks like the equations of motion have changed with the appearance of the Lagrange multiplier field $\lambda$ in equation (6).
In fact though, using the condition that $\partial_\mu J^\mu=0$, one can show, by adding the time derivative of (5) to the divergence of (6), that:
$$\partial_i \partial_i \lambda =0.\tag{8}$$
So that (at least with appropriate boundary conditions?) $\lambda$ is constant and the equations of motion are not changed after all.
Question
My question is, does this hold generally? Given a gauge theory (e.g., $SU(N)$ Yang-Mills), if one adds the gauge condition as a constraint with a Lagrange multiplier, are the resulting Euler-Lagrange equations always equivalent to the original ones, just supplemented with the gauge condition?

OP has correctly identified the mechanism in their example: In order for OP's action (4) to be gauge invariant, we must assume the continuity equation (3). Eq. (3) in turn implies that the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ is a harmonic function (8), so that with appropriate boundary conditions, $\lambda$ disappears from the Euler-Lagrange (EL) eq. (6).
More generally, one may show that in any gauge theory, if a gauge fixing is complete, i.e., the gauge functions are determined uniquely by the gauge conditions, the EL equations derived from the gauge-fixed action are equivalent to those derived from the original action supplemented with the gauge conditions, cf. Ref. 1.
For other examples, see e.g. my Phys.SE answers here & here.
References:

H. Motohashi, T. Suyama & K. Takahashi, Phys. Rev. D 94 (2016) 124021, arXiv:1608.00071.


The answer is 'yes' under the condition that $\lambda$ is independent of $x^\mu$. If $\lambda$ depends on $x^\mu$ it contributes in the equations of motion and the conservation laws.
Note that $\lambda$ is not constant. If it were dL/d$\lambda$ would be meaningless and Eq. (7) would not follow.
